# How to properly use POST with nested serializer in Django?

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

This is the first time I am working with Django Rest Framework and I am stuck on a general issue. I tried many other stackoverflow solutions and other solutions available on google but nothing worked for me.

**My Models:**

```
class Gender(models.Model):
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.gender

class User(models.Model):

    first_name    = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_name     = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    email_id      = models.EmailField(max_length=100, default="")
    city          = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    state         = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    country       = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    zip_code      = models.CharField(max_length=6, blank=True)
    mobile_number = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
    birthdate     = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    gender        = models.ForeignKey(Gender, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='user_gender')
    joined        = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name
```

I want when creating a new user, we use gender from only the available genders in the **Gender Model**

**My Serializers**

```
class GenderSerilizer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Gender
        exclude = [
                    'id',
                  ]              

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    gender = GenderSerilizer()
    class Meta:
       model = User
       fields = [
                'id',
                'first_name',
                'last_name',
                'email_id',
                'city',
                'state',
                'country',
                'zip_code',
                'mobile_number',
                'birthdate',
                'gender',
            ]


def create(self, validated_data):
    gender_data = validated_data.pop('gender')
    user = User.objects.create(**validated_data)
    Gender.objects.create(user=user, **gender_data)
    return user
```

**My views**

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):

def list(self, request):
    """
    """
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer = UserSerializer(queryset, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)

def retrieve(self, request, pk):
    """
    """
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    user = get_object_or_404(queryset, pk=pk)
    serializer = UserSerializer(user)
    return Response(serializer.data)

def create(self, request):
    """
    """
    serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)

    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

def update(self, request, pk):
    """
    """
    pass

def destroy(self, request, pk):
    """
    """
    pass
```

Whenever I try to pass data with the POST method

```
{
    "first_name": "Sample Name",
    "last_name": "Sample Surname",
    "email_id": "admin@sample.com",
    "city": "Sample City",
    "state": "Sample State",
    "country": "IND",
    "zip_code": "000000",
    "mobile_number": "1234567890",
    "birthdate": "2001-01-01",
    "gender": {
        "gender": "Male"
    }
}
```

I receive this error
[image: Error I get when I try to use post method]

I have tried different solutions available on internet but I think I am making a lot of mistakes in my code. I expect to pass data like this in the above json format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the other way around. `User` has a `ForeignKey` for `gender`, therefore it's not `Gender` that expects the `user` keyword argument, but it's `User` that expects the `gender` keyword argument.

It's quite safe is to use `gender = Gender.objects.get_or_create(...)` with your parameters if you want also to create that entry in DB, then create a `User` instance with your `Gender` object as keyword argument

```
user = User(..., gender=gender)
```

and then just `return user`, which will have the `gender` set.